# Changing visibility of the Toolbar at runtime looks terrible

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-toolbar

I've written an application that has one Activity and a number of Fragments, which are hosted by a ViewPager. I have initialized a Toolbar in MainActivity, which I access from each of the pages in the ViewPager. Some pages require the Toolbar but others don't, therefore I'm programmatically setting the visibility to GONE or VISIBLE in their respective onCreate() methods.

The issue is that as the ViewPager pre-loads all the fragments into memory and calls their onCreate() methods in sequence as a result. This results in the Toolbar being visible, prior to hiding upon launching the app.

What can I do to rectify this issue?

```
MainActivity.java
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)                                      
    {
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Fragment1.java

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Fragment2.java

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Change place, where you are setting visibility - from fragments to ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener -> onPageSelected (of course you have to add this listeber to ViewPager by viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener